# What was the first time that a life clock was used in sci-fi?

Tags: history-of

The concept of a life-clock has been used numerous times in sci-fi.

A recent example is the 2011 film [In Time](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk), where everyone has a clock built into their arm that starts to countdown to zero once they reach 25 years old.

The 1987 film, [The Price of Life](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Price_of_Life_(1987_film)) has a similar plot and concept as *In Time*.

The 1976 film, [Logan's Run](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run_(film)), which is based on the [1967 novel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run) of the same name, has a similar plot with a life clock in the palm of an individuals hand which counts down to when an individual reaches 30 (in the film) or 21 (in the novel).

**Is there any story before 1967 that contains a life clock where an individuals life is counted down?**

For this question I would count any story where the life clock counts down automatically and an individual would know how much time they have left by easily checking the clock.

I would **not** count the following types of "life clock" to fit the scope of this question.

- ["Repent, Harlequin!" Said the Ticktockman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Repent,_Harlequin!%22_Said_the_Ticktockman)- while this story requires everyone to follow a strict time schedule where any lateness is removed from the individual's life, the individuals themselves do not have life clocks.
- [Half a Life (Star Trek: The Next Generation)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_a_Life_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))- In this story individual's voluntarily choose euthanasia to prevent the aged from becoming a burden to the younger generation and it is not automatic.
- [Learning Curve, (Stargate SG1)](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Learning_Curve) - The Orbanian children have nanites removed from their system, this "kills" their personality but not them as a being.

Comment: In Heinlein's "Life-Line" (1939), there's an invention that can tell an individual how much time remains to them. There's not a countdown per se.

Comment: As a side comment, it would surprise me if the sci-fi "life clock" idea has not been inspired by the fantasy trope "Death's Hourglass", see https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathsHourglass (the "mythology" section is particularly interesting)

Comment: Well, and the Fates of Greek mythology measuring out and cutting the thread of life.

Comment: Does it need to be a clock or can it be another object that can be used for roughly the same purpose (eg a candle burning down)? Should everyone have such an object? Does it have to be something the person has on their person or have access to? Where does one draw the line for what should be considered sci-fi?

Comment: If individuals are not necessarily aware (matching Greek myth and others) but it still needs to be a visible countdown, then "Godfather Death" (collected by the Brothers Grimm, 1812) fits with candles.  Normally only Death itself sees them, though.  But in terms of an always-visible life clock that people carry with them, I can't think of anything earlier than *Logan's Run*.

Comment: In Time's most similar precursor is Time is Money by Lee Falk Playboy Dec1975. https://mandrake-comics.blogspot.com/2009/02/time-is-money-short-story-by-lee-falk.html?m=1 TALES OF Tomorrow 1952 Time to Go. Is an early example of time = money but lacks the transfer clock of In Time. 
https://youtu.be/ZXMkgBmV-mU?si=IquydIm8JKoNOkkQ

Comment: In the 1939 movie _The Wizard of Oz_, the Wicked Witch of the West puts out an hourglass where supposedly Dorothy will die when the sand runs out. Not in the book BTW.

Comment: "The Ration Ticket" by Marcel Aymé (1942) is about the government allowing people to live a certain amount of days each month, varying depending on the person's social status. So they give people a certain number of tickets, one ticket representing one day of life. When people run out of tickets, they are executed, and then brought back to life the next month.

Comment: @J-J-J having read a translated version of the story I would say this fits the bill. The individuals aren't executed but just disappear and individuals can buy extra tickets to extend their time, you should add this as an answer

Comment: I wouldn't count deaths hourglass as meeting the scope of this question unless each individual has the ability to know their time, if only death does then it wouldn't count

Comment: @A.Steer I used the word execution purposefully :) I'm totally nitpicking here and it's not a hill I'll die on, but I think it's defensible to say people are executed, as it's basically a death sentence ordered by the authorities (even if the method of killing is unusual). In any case, thanks for the feedback, I'll turn that into an answer, even if I suspect someone else might eventually come up with an earlier example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The Ration Ticket* (original title: "La Carte") by Marcel Aymé (1942) is about the government allowing people to live a certain amount of days each month, varying depending on the person's social status and "usefulness". So they give people a certain number of tickets, one ticket representing one day of life. When people run out of tickets, they die –literally disappearing– and then they are brought back to life the next month.

People who are deemed as "useless" get fewer tickets than others (e.g. old people get 6 days of life each month, Jewish people get only half a day – reflecting the context and time of the story publication). As tickets can be exchanged, a black market of time arises, and some people absurdly end up with more days of life than there are days in the month.

It was published as a short story in the newspaper *[La Gerbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Gerbe)* in 1942, and republished in 1943 in the anthology *Le Passe-Muraille*.

As others mentioned in comments, a closely related concept is the "Death's Hourglass", also related to the [thread of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fates) in ancient mythology.